# Unable to install motherboard in the correct height position

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I just bought a new chassis for my PC, the Commander MS-I (Snow Edition). When I tried to install the motherboard I noticed it is at an incorrect height so I am unable to install the graphics card.

[image]
[image]

The motherboard is an Asus M4A77.

I don't understand where I'm failing!

Comment: I don’t get what’s on the first photo...? Also, it looks like you didn’t properly screw in the spacer screw thingy. I also don’t see where to graphics card comes into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove that brass stud on which you are installing the motherboard. That small bump on which you are inserting the stud does the job of the stud. The brass studs are used in chassis which have a flat motherboard tray. Your chassis already have those small elevation for installing the motherboard, there is no need for using those studs. Just align your board with those small bumps and screw your board directly to those bumps.